# Confusion over apk resource files and internal/external files in Android

Tags: android

I am writing an app that has a HorizontalSrollView composed of a LinearLayout that is composed of ImageViews.

I have default images for the HorizontalScrollView in the res/drawable folder. These images should check against a list of images on a server somewhere and if the files are different, the new ones should download and other files that doesn't exist on the file but on the device should be removed.

All that works, except for during my debugging process I have a question. Every time I click "run" on eclipse, does the internal and external storage of my app get removed clean or do the files stay there even if I am installing a newer "version" of my app?

Comment: Short and clear: The files stay there.